# WooCommerce Variable Product Swatches Are Disabled, Don't Know Why

Tags: variables, product, woocommerce

I've recently been working on a new Wordpress site using the WooCommerce and official Woocommerce Variable Product Swatches plugin.

My issue is that the product variation swatches have stopped working on their own. Here's a page for an example: http://butterlane.com/butterlanedev/product/cupcake/

The image swatches lined up along the top should switch the product image when clicked. Everything was working fine before but now the swatches are greyed out and i can see in the CSS that they've been switched to a .disabled class

I've tried creating a brand new product with brand new variations and the page still won't let me click on any of the swatches. I'm truly at a loss as to how this could have stopped working on its own. Hopefully someone with experience using the WooCommerce Variable Product Swatches plugin can help me figure out whats going on.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: have you contacted WooThemes support?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to turn off your swatches plugin and see if there are still "disabled" classes in the select dropdown list for your variations in the single product view page. If the class is still there then the plugin works how it should.

The variations are disabled if there are no more stocks in the inventory or is not available for purchase. Check your variable products for their stock quantity and price in each variation.

Comment: This was the correct answer, it turns out that i you need to have at least a few product variations set up on the backend or it will show up as disabled.

Answer (score 0):

i believe there's a conflict in what the new Woocommerce (2.05) and what the last version of the plugin are meant to do with the other variation images once one has been selected. I'm guessing that the variation plugin uses one of the same trigger ID's in it's javascript as something else WooCommerce has chosen to use (there are only so many logical names for these things).

At this time it basically kills the ability to buy any of the products with variations... which is 'less than useful', for the moment I suggest turning off the plugin and using the default select list, which while ugly at least allows selection.

Waiting for this to get sorted out myself... and since WooThemes have decided to host on the slowest servers on the planet, I can't actually view their website to check the latest version of the plugin.

I guess i'll be pinging them on twitter.